# Efficient STAR selection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum

There is a type of selection called [STAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STAR_voting) which is an acronym for "Score then Automatic Runoff". This is used in a number of algorithmic methods but the typical example is voting. In pandas, this is use to select a single column under this metric. The standard "score" selection is to select the column of the dataframe with the highest sum. This can simply accomplished by

```py
df.sum().idxmax()
```

What is the most efficient pythonic way to do a STAR selection? The method works but first taking the two columns with the highest sum then taking the winner as the column which has the higher value more often between those two. I can't seem to write this in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my take on it

Sample `df`

```
Out[1378]:
   A  B  C  D
0  5  5  1  5
1  0  1  5  5
2  3  3  1  3
3  4  5  0  4
4  5  5  1  1
```

**Step 1**: Use `sum`, `nlargest`, and slice columns for `Score step`

```
df_tops = df[df.sum().nlargest(2, keep='all').index]

Out[594]:
   B  D
0  5  5
1  1  5
2  3  3
3  5  4
4  5  1
```

**Step 2**: compare `df_tops` agains `max` of `df_tops` to create boolean result. finally, `sum` and call `idxmax` on it

```
finalist = df_tops.eq(df_tops.max(1), axis=0).sum().idxmax()    

Out[608]: 'B'
```

Or you may use `idxmax` and `mode` for `step 2`. This returns a series of top column name

```
finalist = df_tops.idxmax(1).mode()

Out[621]:
0    B
dtype: object
```

After you have the top column, just slice it out

```
df[finalist]

Out[623]:
   B
0  5
1  1
2  3
3  5
4  5
```

---

**Note**: in case `runner-up` columns are summing to the same number, step 2 picks only one column. If you want it to pick both same ranking/votes runner-up columns, you need use `nlargest` and `index` instead of `idxmax` and the output will be array

```
finalist = df_tops.eq(df_tops.max(1), axis=0).sum().nlargest(1, keep='all').index.values

Out[615]: array(['B'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Great thanks! Was hoping for a clean one liner but this is a fair bit shorter than my current implementation.